# Seg Fault when calling SDL_BlitSurface a second time

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-2

I'm using SDL and SDL_Image to load images to be used as textures for opengl.

I'm trying to load a spritesheet with multiple images arranged in a horizontal row (in the same image)

```
void load_spritesheet(std::string key, const char *file_name, int width, int height, int nframes) {
    GLuint *texture = new GLuint[nframes];
    auto src = IMG_Load(file_name);
    auto dstrect = new SDL_Rect{0, 0, width, height};

    for(int i = 0; i < nframes; i++) {
        auto dst = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, width, height, 1, src->format->Rmask, src->format->Gmask, src->format->Bmask, src->format->Amask);
        auto rect = new SDL_Rect { i*width, 0, width, height };
        SDL_BlitSurface(src, rect, dst, dstrect);
        load_gltex(dst, &texture[i]);
        SDL_FreeSurface(dst);
    }

    SPRITESHEET_CACHE[key] = texture;
    SDL_FreeSurface(src);
}
```

I stepped through the code, and on the first iteration of the loop it works fine. On the second iteration I get a seg fault on the call to `SDL_BlitSurface`, none of the pointers passed in are NULL and none of the surfaces are locked or anything like that. I'm sure that my rectangles are within the bounds of each surface.

Here's some values from gdb at the point right before it segfaults:

```
print i
1

print *src
{flags = 0, format = 0x847100, w = 416, h = 32, pitch = 1664, pixels = 0x87c5f0, userdata = 0x0, locked = 0, lock_data = 0x0, clip_rect = {x = 0, y = 0, w = 416, h = 32}, map = 0x8537b0, refcount = 1}

print *dst
{flags = 0, format = 0x855ec0, w = 32, h = 32, pitch = 4, pixels = 0x84d1f0, userdata = 0x0, locked = 0, lock_data = 0x0, clip_rect = {x = 0, y = 0, w = 32, h = 32}, map = 0x6bdfc0, refcount = 1}

print *rect
{x = 32, y = 0, w = 32, h = 32}

print *dstrect
{x = 0, y = 0, w = 32, h = 32}
```

Is it unsafe to call `SDL_BlitSurface` twice on the same surface or something like that? Thanks.

Comment: You should inspect the values returned by all those functions, `SDL_BlitSurface` in particular. Also your program leaks memory because you never delete stuff allocated with `new`. `SDL_Rect` can be allocated on the stack. It is also strange that you supply 1 as depth for `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` call, typically it should be 32.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I realized I can change those `new SDL_Rect` calls to be allocated on the stack. And I inspected the return of `SDL_BlitSurface`, it returns zero on the first call (which according to the SDL docs means it was successful, it would be nonzero if there was an error)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the error was caused by improperly setting the depth on the call to `SDL_CreateRGBSurface`

I was passing in a `1` when I really should've been passing the correct value (`32` in this case)

Once I corrected that the segfault went away.

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurface#Remarks